# Calling public array of structs using web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays

Good day.

I've got an array of structs such as:

```
User[] public users;


struct User{
    uint idNum;
    string name;
    address userAddress;
}
```

And I'm trying to get the array of users with web3.js using:

```
contract = web3.eth.contract([ABI]).at("0x0..");
var users = contract.users();
```

So far everything works fine, but when I'm trying to get the size of the array I always gets 3 - I assume it only counts how many fields each user have but what I want is to count how many users are there.

I understand the The variable "users" (in JS) is a function and not an array per se, but I just can't find any way to directly interact with the array.

Comment: Try `var users = contract.users.length` in your `.js` file,

Comment: The result is 3 (even though the array is has 7 users). I can get the information on any specific user by typing his number manually contract.users(4) -> {idNum:4, name: "number 4", userAddress: "0x0.."}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function getUsersCount() public constant returns(uint) {
    return users.length;
}

function getUser(uint index) public constant returns(uint, string, address) {
    return (users[index].idNum, users[index].name, users[index].userAddress);
}
```

You should then be able use the statements:

```
> var numberOfUsers = contract.usersCount();
undefined
> numberOfUsers
5
> var user0 = contract.users(0)
[123, "User 123", "0xbeefee3ad17cd9aca6fd5343a53a513685c7e0ed"]
> var user1 = contract.getUser(1)
[234, "User 234", "0xbeefee3ad17cd9aca6fd5343a53a513685c7e0ed"]
> var lastUser = arrayStruct.users(numberOfUsers-1)
undefined
> lastUser
[567, "User 567", "0xbeefee3ad17cd9aca6fd5343a53a513685c7e0ed"]
```

And responding to the comment by `Nikhil M`, the statement below always returns 0 for me. I don't know if it is a design feature or a bug.

```
> var users = contract.users.length
undefined
> users
0
```

---

#### Gas Cost

The call to `contract.usersCount()`, `contract.users(x)` and `contract.getUser()` don't change the blockchain data and don't cost gas. From [Greeter](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter),

> Run the Greeter
>   In order to call your bot, just type the following command in your terminal:
>
> ```
> greeter.greet();
> ```
>
> Since this call changes nothing on the blockchain, it returns instantly and without any gas cost. You should see it return your greeting:

This is the contract code that I used:

```
contract ArrayStruct {

    struct User {
        uint idNum;
        string name;
        address userAddress;
    }

    User[] public users;

    function addUser(uint _idNum, string _name, address _userAddress) public returns(uint) {
        users.length++;
        users[users.length-1].idNum = _idNum;
        users[users.length-1].name = _name;
        users[users.length-1].userAddress = _userAddress;
        return users.length;
    }

    function getUsersCount() public constant returns(uint) {
        return users.length;
    }

    function getUser(uint index) public constant returns(uint, string, address) {
        return (users[index].idNum, users[index].name, users[index].userAddress);
    }
}
```

You will have to pay the gas for inserting the contract into the blockchain as shown by the `gas: 1000000` field in the following statement:

```
var contract = arrayStructContract.new({
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
  data: arrayStructCompiled.ArrayStruct.code,
  gas: 1000000
}, function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if(!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " +
          contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
    }
})
```

And you will have to pay the gas when you change the blockchain data, as shown by the `gas: 500000` in the following statements:

```
contract.addUser(123, "User 123", eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: arrayStructCompiled.ArrayStruct.code, 
  gas: 500000
});

contract.addUser(234, "User 234", eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: arrayStructCompiled.ArrayStruct.code, 
  gas: 500000
});
```

Comment: This is a good approach to the problem, But I was hopping to get the data using only JS in order to save some gas (users.length will be updated from time to time).

Comment: The call to `contract.usersCount()`, `contract.users(x)` and `contract.getUser()` don't change the blockchain data and don't cost gas.

Comment: but won't it increase the deployment cost? and what will happen when a user will be added/removed?

Comment: I've added the details about the deployment cost to the answer under **Gas Cost**

Answer (score 1):

Here's code I use...probably just a work around, but from my node console I use:

```
var i = 4;
var j = 0;
while (i>3) {var x = contract.users.call(j);j++;var i = x.length} 
j-1
```

So then that last j-1 should print out the length of your list

---