# Looking for working example of web3.getStorageAt() API usage

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, ethereumj

The documentation at http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage commonly linked to in other questions does not go into enough detail to replicate the process for complex types like dynamic arrays.  Following the instructions I to try access my contract storage, I can easily get the first few elementary types but I can't seem to find the right address for a dynamic sized array.

The dynamic array is at index 3 (position 4) and it is an array of struct.

I can easily get the array length with:

> web3.eth.getStorageAt(myContractAddress, 3);

But I cannot get any array values using:

> var hash = web3.sha3("0x04"), {encoding:"hex"});
>   web3.eth.getStorageAt(myContractAddress, hash);

I have also tried with "0x4" and "0x3" and "0x5" and many other combinations.

Can someone please provide specific examples using the web3 library to retrieve the address of a dynamic array?

Comment: I have restructured the question, please note I have (and did so in the original) added a reference the commonly linked url and mentioned that it is insufficient to solve my problem. Please consider remoing the duplicate tag.

Comment: Hi, will let community decide on this.  Some things to consider, in addition to the comments I posted in the linked answer.  Easiest: Contract can have a function that takes an index and returns the value: [example](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3114/calling-public-array-of-structs-using-web3).  Otherwise, watch out for the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and getting [closed for not creating a minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056099/why-isnt-this-code-working-indicates-errors)