# Push to dynamical array of structs using loop in external function

Tags: solidity, remix, struct

```
struct testR{
    bytes32 name;
    int32 count;
}

testR[] public tests;

function createTest(bytes32[] names) external returns (bool success) {
    uint256 len = names.length;
    for (uint8 i=0;i<len;i++){
        tests.push(testR({name: names[i], count: 0}));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's my code. When I deploy this contract to my private network, function createTest just doesn't work, I pass array of converted to HEX strings, then when I call public array "tests" it always returns me 0x and null.
If I try to compile and run this contract in Remix using JVM, it gives such error:

```
undefined errored: VM error: invalid opcode.
invalid opcode  The constructor should be payable if you send value.
The execution might have thrown.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

I guess there's something wrong with my loop but it seems so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rearranged a few things and the code below worked for me.  Also make sure you're actually inputting an array or you'll get an error too.

```
testR[] public tests;
struct testR{
    bytes32 name;
    int32 count;
}


function createTest(bytes32[] names) external returns (bool success) {
    uint256 len = names.length;
    for (uint8 i=0;i<len;i++){
        tests.push(testR(names[i],0));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm using web3.js to access my contract from local domain.
For example, I define var one = web.toHex('string');
Then I call contract.createTest([one]);
It returns me transaction hash. Then I start miner, wait for one block to be mined, and call contract.tests(0,1, callback) and it returns me ["0x", e]

Comment: I think that's just an issue of accessing the array.  Here's a better way to do it: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3114/calling-public-array-of-structs-using-web3

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was in passing the arguments from browser's console using web3.js